# Impure Pipe VS Event Subscription in Pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe

I have a simple user requirement: to allow the user to select a time zone. Once the user selects a time zone, all the dates in the app should be transformed according to that time zone. It's important to note that there are many dates in the app.

For date transformation, I am using a custom Pipe. However, when the user changes their time zone, it gets updated in the service, but the pipe doesn't detect that change instantly. It takes some time to reflect the change. However, when I set my pipe to 'impure', it detects the change instantly. I know using impure pipe is not considered good so what should I do? Or is it suitable for the case? What about having an event subscription in the Pipe instead? Or any other best practice to tackle this?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service'

@Pipe({
  name: 'displayDate',
  pure: false
})
export class DisplayDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
    }

    transform(value: any, format?: string): any {
        if (!value || !this.auth?.timezone) return ''

        return moment(value).tz(this.auth?.timezone).format(format ?? 'MMM D, YYYY') + ` (${this.auth.timezone})`
    }
}
```

Comment: With the dependency on a service, you lose one of the main benefits of a pipe which is performance gains through caching. Some easy alternatives are shared functions and service calls to perform this same operation, but the syntax and reuse of a pipe are much nicer.

One possible alternative is to pass the timezone in as an argument in the pipe. That way you can preserve the input/output caching and pure-ness of the pipe which is just responsible for the transformation.

Comment: Umm that would be cumbersome as I have many components displaying date. Using pipe is much cleaner as I don't have to inject service in every component to get timezone info.

Comment: Exactly. With your current implementation you're trading the convenience and reuse for the performance which is valid. You're just using the pipe as a global transform function and won't be able to use it to cache the output.